# Storing model is session. Is there any better way for it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model class like following

```
public class ProductModel
{
    string ProductName { get; set; }
    int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller I have an Action item

```
public ActionResult ShowProduct()
{
      return View();
}
```

In my view user has two text boxes; where they enter product name and quantity.  The first time they come in on this page these fields are empty. Once they enter values in these text boxes they hit a Next button which take them to a next page where they have to enter additional information about order.
On that page I have a back button and they can come back to this first page. Problem is I need to display the information that they entered in first page but on the second page I don’t have that ProductModel  anymore. I can store that model in session but not sure if there is any better pattern of doing it in MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would steer clear of Session and TempData. If you're using MVC, and your views are separated by full postbacks, (not Ajax) maybe you could use a view model pattern across different controller actions.

```
public class OrderController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ShowProduct()
    {
        return View(new ProductViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoOrderStuff(ProductViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // OrderViewModel would contain some product data 
            // to be used in the DoOrderStuff view
            return View(new OrderViewModel(vm));
        }

        // error, go back to Page 1
        return View("ShowProduct", vm);
    }
}
```

This gives you room for validation while still following the wizard style views you described.

### Caveat I just realized with this:

If you have a bunch of successive views, your user experience would probably suffer without a lot of hacking together of different view models. E.g. customer is on page 5 of the wizard, and wants to go back to page 2--my answer in its simplest form wouldn't accommodate that. However, with a good abstraction of the values in all your screens, it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what the Session dictionary was intended to be used for.  You may look into using TempData but in essence it is just a lightweight version of Session.  I don't see anything wroth with what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to store this in the Session/TempData (watch out, how TempData works surprisingly changed quite a bit from MVC 2 to MVC 3). Your next button sounds like a POST, and then you do some sort of Redirect. If instead you made your form POST to the URL you wanted to display next, the `ProductModel` would be passed right along, and you could then pass it from the Action to the View, through either the Model or ViewData.

Comment: @Faktorovich out of curiosity: what changed in TempData between MVC2 and 3?

Comment: @epignosisx http://robertcorvus.com/warning-mvc-nets-tempdata-now-persists-across-screens/. He links to the real article, but I like his better.

Comment: @Faktorovich thanks for sharing the link. I was not awared of the change.

Comment: @epignosisx no worries, a bug involving the change screwed with me for quite a while.